# Does iTunes provide a way that I can structure a Smart Playlist to include all songs from three non-Smart playlists along with X GB of random music?

Tags: itunes, playlists, smart-playlist, itunes-10

I have three playlists: P1, P2, and P3, along with the Music library. I always want all songs in P1, P2, and P3 to be in the smart playlist. However, every time I clear the Smart Playlist, I want all songs in P1, P2, and P3 to be restored to it, but I also want X number or mega/gigabytes of music from the Music playlist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For this you  need to create two smart playlists. One that contains your X megabytes of random music and another one that contains all the music from P1, P2, P3, and the other smart playlist.

Comment: Wow...this is so obvious, I don't know why I didn't think of it...-_-